# How to get a binary, without the .app, using qmake on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmake

I am using qmake for a c++ project, on macOS.

When I compile the project, the output is a **.app** folder, **which contains my binary**, and some other files for macos.

Can I add an option on my **.pro** file to compile the project and have the binary, **without having the .app** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Add the following to the project file:

`CONFIG -= app_bundle`